# Bitmap not successfully retrieved from MySQL using Java

Tags: java, android, mysql, bitmap, android-imageview

I'm posting data to a URL from Java, which uses PHP to return a `json_encode(d)` blob from the MySQL field on a web server.

Now, when I use this returned data (using `InputStream` or `getBytes`) to create a `bitmap` and set a `ImageView` to this bitmap using `setImageBitmap`, I get empty imageview. i.e., `decodeByteArray` or `decodeStream` returns NULL.

I have no problem retrieving textual details, retrieving images is an issue. Here is the code snipped of Java and PHP.

This is my onCreate method of Java:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

super.onCreate(icicle);

setContentView(R.layout.loginlayout);
TextView tv1, tv2, tv3, tv4, tv5;
imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

button  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dispuser);
tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv3);
tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv4);
tv5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv5);


SharedPreferences userDetails = this.getSharedPreferences("logindetails",      MODE_PRIVATE);
String username = userDetails.getString("username", "");
String password = userDetails.getString("password", "");

button.setOnClickListener(this);


httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

httppost = new HttpPost("myurl");


try{

nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));



httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){
    
    entity = response.getEntity();
    
    
    if(entity != null) {
        
        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
        
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(convertStreamToString(instream));
        
    


String sex = jsonResponse.getString("Sex");
String age = jsonResponse.getString("Age");
String name = jsonResponse.getString("Name");
String phone = jsonResponse.getString("Phone");
String pic = jsonResponse.getString("picture");

byte[] image = Base64.encodeBytesToBytes(pic.getBytes("UTF-8"));

imageview.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length));


 tv1.setText("Welcome " + username);
 tv2.setText("Your  is Name: " + name);
 tv3.setText("Your phone " + phone);
 tv4.setText("Your a  " + sex );
 tv5.setText("Your age is " + age);
 

}
} 

}
catch (Exception e) {

e.printStackTrace();



}
finally {
httppost.abort();
}
}
```

and on the PHP side:

```
    <?
    include 'connect.php';

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM applogin WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'");

    $num = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($num == 1)
    {
    while($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
    $output = $list;
    }
    echo json_encode($output);
    mysql_close();
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You said that the image exists as a `blob` on the server side, but my reading indicates that `json_encode` won't send binary data. are you forgetting to `Base64` encode on the server before sending to the client? I'd also be printing the payload to make sure it contains the expected data.

Comment: Thank you Altaf and David. Your help helped me figure out a solution. On the server side, I coded as David instructed and java code follows Altaf's idea.

Comment: Vijay, could you post your code as an answer? - I am doing something almost identical with json_encode, but not sure how I do base64 on just the blob row and not my entire array or do i do it to the entire array?

Comment: Note: at the time of writing, the PHP code in this question **has a pretty big SQL injection vulnerability**. Readers are advised not to copy this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
String input;//your pic string 
byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, 0);
BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put json_encode($data) into an array syntax variable.

So Write $data php as an array
For example, mariadb loop

```
$data = array();
    $dCount =0;
    foreach($contacts as $contact) {        

        $email = $contact->email;
        $dCount++;
        
        $r1 = $contact->id;
        
        $data['params_name1'][]= array("name" => $contact->name, "age" => $contact->age, "username" => $contact->username);
    }

$data['params_name2'][] = array("status" => $status, "message" => $message, "row" => $dCount);
echo json_encode($data);
$pdo = null;
```

You can replace params_name1 to table
and params_name2 to title.

Then, on android async task result:
You can apply image64 to imageview picture, after get string image64:

```
ImageView image1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
//after get image64:
                String image64r = image64.substring (image64.indexOf (",") +1);)
                byte [] decodedString = Base64.decode (image64r.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                Bitmap decodedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length); 
                image1.setImageBitmap(decodedImage);
```

You can save image view picture to bitmap later:

```
public void saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage){
    

    File imgFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Profile2.png");

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {           
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imgFile);
        // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            //fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void saveImageViewBitmap(View view) {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();

    float originalWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
    float originalHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"seattled: w=" + String.valueOf(originalWidth) + " h=" + String.valueOf(originalHeight),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
    int targetWidth =200;
    int targetHeight =200;
    float percentage = 100;
    if ((originalWidth > 200)&&(originalHeight > 200)) {
        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"A " + String.valueOf(originalWidth) + " " + String.valueOf(originalHeight),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (originalWidth > originalHeight) {
            percentage = originalWidth/originalHeight;
            targetHeight = 200;
            targetWidth = Math.round(200*percentage);
        }
        else
        {
            percentage = originalHeight/originalWidth;
            targetWidth = 200;
            targetHeight = Math.round(200*percentage);
        }
        
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        String info = df.format(percentage);
        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"percentage: " + info,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        bitmap = scaleBitmap(bitmap, targetWidth, targetHeight);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"too small to scaled " + String.valueOf(originalWidth) + " " + String.valueOf(originalHeight),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    saveToInternalStorage(bitmap);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```